# Removing and re-adding a subview with autolayout

Tags: cocoa, subview, autolayout

When using autolayout, my understanding is that removing a subview ( while holding a reference to it of course), the removed subview still knows its autolayout constraints.

However, when adding it back to the super view later, the subview no longer knows its frame size. 
Rather it seems to get a zero frame.

I assumed that autolayout would auto size it to meet the constraints. Is that not the case? 
I thought auto layout meant don't mess with frame rects. Do I still need to set the initial frame rect when adding the subview, even with auto layout?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

When removing the subview, all the constraints that relate to that subview will be lost. If you need to add the subview again later, then you must add constraints to that subview again.

Typically, I create the constraints in my custom subview. For example:

```
-(void)updateConstraints
{
    if (!_myLayoutConstraints)
    {
        NSMutableArray *constraints = [NSMutableArray array];

       // Create all your constraints here
       [constraints addWhateverConstraints];

       // Save the constraints in an ivar. So that if updateConstraints is called again,
       // we don't try to add them again. That would cause an exception.
       _myLayoutConstraints = [NSArray arrayWithArray:constraints];

       // Add the constraints to myself, the custom subview
       [self addConstraints:_myLayoutConstraints]; 
   }

   [super updateConstraints];
}
```

`updateConstraints` will be called automatically by the Autolayout runtime. The code above goes in your custom subclass of `UIView`.

You're right that in working with Autolayout, you don't want to touch frame sizes. Instead, just update the constraints in `updateConstraints`. Or, better still, set up the constraints so you don't have to.

See my answer on that topic:

[Autolayout UIImageView with programatic re-size not following constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17299223/autolayout-uiimageview-with-programatic-re-size-not-following-constraints/17300238#17300238)

You don't need to set the initial frame. If you do use `initWithFrame`, just set it to `CGRectZero`. Your constraints will - in fact *must* - detail either how big something should be, or other relationships that mean the runtime can deduce the size.

For example, if your visual format is: `@"|-[myView]-|"`, that's everything you need for the horizontal dimension. Autolayout will know to size `myView` to be up to the bounds of the parent `superview` denoted by `|`. It's pretty cool.

Comment: Thanks. That's nice and clear. One note that I asked about Cocoa and not Cocoa-touch, but for others to note, the APIs are (as described by Peter Ammon ofApple) the same or almost the same. The approaches in both worlds should be the same.

Comment: [The documentation](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIView/updateConstraints) says it's **important** to call `[super updateConstraints]` as the final step in your implementation. It should go at the end of your method, not at the beginning.

Comment: yes I think that was introduced with iOS7. Now updated thanks

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see NSView handling CGZeroRect or NSZeroRect quite so well as UIView... please tell me I am imagining that. (do note the tags)

Comment: you mean CGRectZero? I can't comment on NSView but I would imagine it works the same way. Using Auto Layout, you should be working with constraints not frames. Invoking [[UIView alloc] init] will create a CGRectZero view the same as initWithFrame:CGRectZero.

Comment: I must have been sleepy. Indeed initWithFrame can receive it and work fine.

Comment: Is something similar to this possible in Swift?